# Колоссальное время — можно так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, прилагательные

Сейчас в матче с Англией комментатор так выразился. Мне кажется, что "колоссальный" — это о размерах, пространственных характеристиках чего-то, но не может быть о времени. Я прав, или комментатор нормально сказал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

О времени говорят не только в аспекте длительности - к нему применяют и эпитеты, характеризующие его наполненность. Поэтому в дополнение к прилагательным "большое" (огромное, колоссальное, неимоверное) требуется контекст, указывающий на отнесение их именно к длительности. Например, выражение "у нас впереди колоссальное время" вызывает лёгкое недоумение (то ли это о количестве времени, то ли эмоционально сказано о времени великих дел или удовольствий), в то время как выражение "*потратил* **колоссальное время** на что-то" содержит элемент, указывающий на **количество** ("потратил") и потому воспринимается нормально. Подобная проблема существует и с прилагательными "большое", "огромное". В сочетании с "большим" принято явно указывать на "количество" (*большое количество времени*), если не заменять все выражение синонимичным (много времени, уйма времени). С "огромным" же, по-видимому, допустимо такое выражение без слова "количество" как "*требуется огромное время* на что-то", с косвенным указанием на расход времени.

Answer (score 2):

**Время - многозначное слово**, к двум его первым значениям относится:

1) **Мера длительности** всего происходящего, существующего, измеряемая секундами, минутами, часами, сутками и т. п.  **Последовательная смена** минут, часов, дней, лет и т. п. 2)  **Отрезок, промежуток в** последовательной смене минут, часов, дней, лет и т. п.

Этот промежуток времени может иметь **различные определения**, оценивающие его восприятие по величине, например: **короткое, длинное, маленькое, большое, колоссальное.**

К примеру, **короткое время - это короткий промежуток времени.**

Примеры

Как же убить **это длинное время** и куда деваться от зноя! [А. П. Чехов. Степь (1888)]

Сколько уж раз на деле убеждался Егор, что всё же человек никогда до конца не забывается ― всегда, даже **в страшно короткое время,** успеет подумать: что будет? [Василий Шукшин. Калина красная (1973)]

Тетя Лиза говорила, что **самое большое время** пребывания культурного гостя ― это три часа. [И. А. Ефремов. Лезвие бритвы (1959-1963)]

**Дрессированное время** шло в ногу с ним, никакие события не позволяли ему уклониться в сторону, расцвести на стороне диковатым цветком поэзии или греха, и **мое маленькое время**, как собачка на коротком поводке, тащилось за ним… [Ирина Полянская. Прохождение тени (1996)]

И Панков минуты три-четыре ― а на сцене это **огромное время** ― что-то импровизировал. [Татьяна Шмыга. Счастье мне улыбалось... (2000)]

Это **колоссальное время** было затрачено в основном на поиск как можно большего количества ошибок в действиях экипажа. [Валентин Дудин. Чужое небо (2004)]

Answer (score 1):

Мне тоже не нравится такой "эпитет".
Но я бы отнес эту ошибку к мелким стилистическим, не более. Формально можно сослаться на переносное значение колоссальный, вон Niemand с подачи Кузнецова приравнивает колоссальный к огромному. И формально, хотя слух и царапает, тут трудно возразить, "колоссальный" давно перестало относиться исключительно к пространственным характеристикам.

Правда, тут еще один момент надо отметить. В разговорной речи некая физическая (и не только) характеристика давно и безвозвратно стала обозначать не только саму себя, но и свою величину.

В соответствующих контекстах "Время" = величина времени, "длина" = размер длины, "сила" - величина силы и проч.

Это не всем нравится, в том есть некий философский вопрос, но в рамках стилистики ничего не остается, как принять к сведению как данность.
Никто ж не будет (вне учебника по крайней мере) требовать говорить "величина тока 5 ампер" вместо "ток - пять ампер". То же самое и со временем. В выражении "колоссальное время" под "временем" вполне может пониматься именно "величина времени", а уж она-то со всех позиций вполне легально может быть "колоссальной".

Так что и весь оборот следует признать правомерным. Хотя и - с учетом сказанного - немного шероховатым.

Comment: Нее, насчёт времени как величины времени я вообще не напрягался, я именно об эпитете спрашивал.

Comment: *Нее, насчёт времени как величины времени я вообще не напрягался* - а вот тогда-то, если не напрягаться, то использование "эпитета" становится сомнительным. ну что такое время, если его не мерить, хотя бы субъективной "шкалой"?! Без понимания, что речь идет о количестве? "Колоссальная вода"?! "Колоссальная музыка"? - это о качестве. А время как понятие явно не может быть лучше или хуже... Впрочем, это умозрительный разговор, комментатор явно имел в виду количество "времени". Т.е. "время" как величину "времени". "колоссальное время"  = "очень много времени".

Comment: Может, и правда, мне подсознательно это резануло слух именно из-за того, что он не сказал "количество", а не из-за прилагательного, как я подумал и тут написал. Не знаю даже уже...)

Answer (score 0):

Если сказано о длительности, то почему бы нет? Колоссальный – огромный по величине, размеру, количеству (Кузнецов). Очень большое время, колоссальное.

Comment: И по какому из этих атрибутов вы оцениваете время? Размер? количество? Величина? )))

Comment: Да по любому можно. И что тут такого смешного – аж на три скобочки?

Comment: И чему равен "размер" времени? "По любому"? )))

Answer (score 0):

"Колоссальное время" звучит плохо (хотя и сложно объяснить, почему). Правильнее было бы "колоссальное количество времени".